# java command line argument to make jar find files in two directories?

Tags: java

I have a jar file which I do not have the source code but want to use.

The jar file prompts for a file to read and generates an output file using a combinatin of the input file and a number of 'helper' files it uses for data.  It works perfecty fine if run from its expected home directory, but I'm trying to write a script which will allow running the jar from anywhere.

The problem is that if I try running the jar file from anywhere other then its home directories it fails to find the support files it needs to properly generate its data.

If I run the file from its expected home directory I have to give the full address of the input file or it won't find it. I would prefer to be able to give just the relative path and Java know to look at whatever directory the person calling my script is in.

Is there a way I can have a bash script pass a command line argument to Java that would ensure that this jar looks at both of the relevant directories (directory of the helper files and the current dir of the person calling the script) when trying to resolve a relative file path?  Something like the `-classpath` argument?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the `--classpath` (or `-cp`) you can tell your Java program where it should take the dependency classes. So, probably if you do like in your *files directory*

```
$JAVA_HOME/bin/java -cp '.:/path/to/the/original/program' My.class myfile.txt
```

then it will wind the program, and find your files as well.

**UPDATE**

If it doesn't work, you can try to force the file loading some other way. The Javadoc says:

> By default the classes in the `java.io` package always
>   resolve relative pathnames against the current user directory.  This
>   directory is named by the system property `user.dir`, and
>   is typically the directory in which the Java virtual machine was
>   invoked.

So, you can try running the program *from the original directory* this way:

```
$JAVA_HOME/bin/java -Duser.dir=/path/to/the/files/directory My.class myfile.txt
```

**UPDATE2**:

As I wrote in a comment, you can try `symlinks`. Execute the following commands *in the original directory*:

```
ln -s /path/to/the/files/directory datafiles

$JAVA_HOME/bin/java My.class datafiles/myfile.txt
```

Comment: I tried that before posting this question, since it seeemd the easiest solution.  It doesn't appear to work.  I assume that the File function doesn't check the classpath when given a relative file?

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but afraid this won't work either.  I already did the funcional equivlant (I was lasier, used a CD command in the script) to try running from the user current directory.  The problem is that if I'm in the user current directory I can't find the helper files in the java home directory, or vice versa.  I would need java to be able to try resolving a realtiave filepath to one of two possible directories.  Duser.dir only allows one path.  It sounds as if this just can't be done without source (or really hacky script ideas as work arounds)

Comment: Maybe you can try `symlinks` - I don't know how many files are affected, but in lucky case you can solve it with a few symlinks.

Answer (score -1):

**Sorry - ignore.  I missed the first line of your question.**

---

You could pass the two paths as an argument to the jar file - then append the path location at runtime.  Many ways to do that, here is one:

```
java -DdirectoryA="/somewhere" -DdirectoryB="/elsewhere" -jar program.jar
```

and in your code

```
String pathA = System.getProperty("directoryA");
```